# What does signal 9 mean in MPI? How to debug?

Tags: c, debugging, mpi

I am currently developing a system that simulates the movements of bodies around the solar system and have been getting the following error when I run my code for larger number of bodies I get the following error.

```
MPT ERROR: MPI_COMM_WORLD rank 26 has terminated without calling MPI_Finalize()

MPT: Received signal 9
```

What does signal 9 mean when running MPI Programs and how can I effectively debug my code when this arises?

Comment: Don't know the first thing about MPI, but in POSIX signal 9 is [SIGKILL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals).

Comment: If on a HPC system with a job submission system, your job might simply have been killed because it exceeds the requested resources.

Comment: That typically occurs when a process is killed by the oom killer. Running dmesg on the compute node can confirm this

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that the cause usually depends from program to program. For me, it seemed to be a memory overflow issue. The link below helped detect the error:

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does-anyone-know-how-to-fix-mpirun-signal-9-killed-problem

In order to fix the error I simply had to free up the memory I had designated for a large boolean array.

```c
void free2DBool(bool ***array) {
  // free the memory 
  free(&((*array)[0][0]));

  // free pointers into memory
  free(*array);
}
```